# How to implement compound configuration variables, or "module level properties?"

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I have a configuration file, `default.py`:

```
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 8080
PROTOCOL = 'http' if PORT != 443 else 'https'
ROOT_STR = '%s://%s:%s' % (PROTOCOL, HOST, PORT)
```

And then I have a `local.py` that overwrites default variables to suit the local environment:

```
PORT = 443
```

How would I dynamically regenerate `PROTOCOL` and `ROOT_STR` as if they were properties of a class, but instead at root level of a module?

The resulting configuration, from changing one variable, would read:

```
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 443
PROTOCOL = 'https'
ROOT_STR = 'https://localhost:443'
```

The expected behavior should model class properties:

```
class Configuration(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = 'localhost'
        self.port = 8080

    @property
    def protocol(self):
        return 'https' if self.port == 443 else 'http'

    @property
    def root_str(self):
        return '%s://%s:%s' % (self.protocol, self.host, self.port)

...
...

>>> c = Configuration()
>>> c.port = 443
>>> c.root_str
'https://localhost:443'
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this than modifying the AST?

Thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access global variables from a function in an imported module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924700/access-global-variables-from-a-function-in-an-imported-module)

Comment: @RNar unfortunately they're different - the problem isn't accessing the variables, it's dynamically regenerating subsequent variables that used a changed variable in their assignment.

Comment: I don't really grok what you're thinking about trying, but wouldn't it make more sense to have `local.py` only exist locally, and use a `try...except ImportError` that imports the `local.py` values if they're there, otherwise leaving the global defaults? Might even be one of those rare good use cases for an `import *` if properly scoped and limited.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I updated the question with a class-level property to demonstrate expected behavior

Comment: Does singleton like class you presented would suit your requirements?

Comment: Potentially. I was trying to avoid it since our current `default configuration` file has >100 settings and probably 20% are computed based on other entries.

Comment: Using a configuration object is a better practice anyway, since it makes testing much easier - you can pass it around instead of relying on mocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a custom Configuration `class` and `metaclass`, the rough implementation is below.

```
import re
import types

CONST_VARS = re.compile(r'[A-Z]+[_A-Z]*')

# Configuration primitives that allow for dynamic
# variable compilation for default/local/dev/etc settings files.
class ConfigType(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, odict):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'vars'):
            cls.vars = {}
        reg_vars = filter(lambda x: CONST_VARS.match(x[0]), odict.items())
        for k, v in reg_vars:
            cls.vars[k] = v
            delattr(cls, k)
        super(ConfigType, cls).__init__(name, bases, cls.vars)


class Configuration(object):
    __metaclass__ = ConfigType

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.vars[key] = value
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        ret = self.vars.get(item)
        if isinstance(ret, types.FunctionType):
            return ret(self)
        return ret
    def as_module(self):
        mod_vars = {}
        for k, v in self.vars.items():
            if isinstance(v, types.FunctionType) and callable(v):
                v = v(self)
            mod_vars[k] = v
        return type('Configuration', (object,), mod_vars)
```

Then, if I create two `Configuration` objects:

**`settings/default.py`**

```
class DatabaseConfig(Configuration):
    MYSQL_DB = 'DEFAULT'
    MYSQL_USER = os.environ.get('MYSQL_USER')
    MYSQL_PASS = os.environ.get('MYSQL_PASS')
    MYSQL_HOST = os.environ.get('MYSQL_HOST', 'localhost')
    MYSQL_PORT = os.environ.get('MYSQL_PORT', 3306)

    def MYSQL_URI(self):
        return 'mysql://{user}:{password}@{server}:{port}'.format(
            user=self.MYSQL_USER,
            password=self.MYSQL_PASS,
            server=self.MYSQL_HOST,
            port=self.MYSQL_PORT )

    def SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI(self):
        return str(self.MYSQL_URI) + '/' + self.MYSQL_DB

DatabaseConfig()
```

**`settings/local.py`**

```
class LocalConfig(Configuration):
    MYSQL_DB = 'mycoolstuff'
    MYSQL_USER = 'root'
    MYSQL_PASS = 'rootpass'
    MYSQL_HOST = '172.17.42.1'  # Docker
    MYSQL_PORT = 3306

Config = LocalConfig()
```

When I import `LocalConfig` my variables will be computed automatically, all functions act as properties and all class attributes as variables.

```
>>> import settings.default
>>> from settings.local import Config
>>> Config.MYSQL_PORT
3306
>>> Config.MYSQL_URI
mysql://root:rootpass@172.17.42.1:3306
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add `from default import *` to the top of your `local.py` file. This should make all the variables and functions in `default.py` available as if they were in `local.py`.

Comment: This "kind of" works, but all the variables that were computed will not get recomputed based on the changes in `local.py` ~ example: if `C = A + B` in `default` where `A` and `B` are also defined, if I change `A` in `local` it should also update the value for `C`

Comment: This is very true. One approach would be to use a class that you can extend (`class BaseSettings(object): ...` in the defaults, followed by `SETTINGS = BaseSettings()` at the bottom and `class LocalSettings(BaseSettings): ...` after the import in the local file, followed by `SETTINGS = LocalSettings()`) or putting the dynamic logic into a manager of sorts through which you use these settings. There's probably more approaches.